# How can I view file position in folder hierarchy (a file tree)?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to view the open file's position in the folder hierarchy? Something like Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, or the project drawer in TextMate?

[image: project drawer in TextMate]
The project drawer in TextMate (Image by [Christian Heilmann](http://www.flickr.com/photos/codepo8/4385059892/)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install the SherloXplorer plugin
( Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager )

once installed:
Toggle Sherlo ON (via its plugin menu)
Load a file.
Go to the Sherlo plugin menu and select 'Go to current file' 
 OR
Go into the Sherlo options and enable "show toolbar menu at bottom". On that toolbar is a button with an 'eye' icon. if enabled, it will follow the currently selected active file automatically.

[image: SherloXplorer: File list only]

Comment: Perfect, also toggling `File list only` sets it up just the way I want!

Comment: Confirming this still works in Summer 2018. The `file list only` setting mentioned by @Louis is to the left of the eye icon at the bottom.